# v-for list diseapears after a second

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, v-for

I have a function which gives me list of objects. After update it renders correctly for a second than the list disappears. Any idea why this is happening ?

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
import { getList, Version } from "@/services/firebaseService";
import { ref, watch } from "vue";
import { useRouter } from "vue-router";

const platformRef = ref(
  useRouter().currentRoute.value.query.platform?.toString()
);
const abiRef = ref(useRouter().currentRoute.value.query.abi?.toString());

const list = ref([] as Version[]);

watch([platformRef, abiRef], async ([platform, abi]) => {
  if (platform) {
    list.value = await getList(platform, abi);
    console.log(list.value);
  }
});
</script>

<template>
  <section>
    <div class="form-selector">
      <div class="form-block">
        <o-radio v-model="platformRef" name="platform" native-value="android"
          >Android</o-radio
        >
      <!-- rest of the form to set values for platform and abi -->
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card" v-for="item in list" :key="item.name">
      {{ item.name }}
    </div>
  </section>
</template>
```

and console output looks correctly (shows proxy to the array)

```
Proxy {}
Object[[Target]]:
 Array(1)0:
  {name: 'v0.2.0-beta.apk', link: 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/...'} 
  [[Prototype]]: Objectlength: 1
  [[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

UPDATE when chenged the function inside `watch` to this:

```js
const result = await getList(platform, abi);
console.log(result);
console.log(result.length)
```

I get correct array but length 0...

Comment: This is some original vue code IMHO. However, the only logical explanation is that your list is first filled in but then gets emptied. :)

Comment: @Wimanicesir forgot to include this, sometimes it renders again after a while...

Comment: What does the `o-radio` component do?

Comment: `o-radio` is radio component from Oruga UI. Means using radios user select platform an ABI...

Answer (score 0):

I think that problem is in this string:

`list.value = await getList(platform, abi);`

You try to set the value field of list, but arrays do not have this field;
Instead, you should use this:

`list = await getList(platform, abi);`

Comment: `list` is not array but ref, so AFAIK the value of `list` is array...

Comment: So why are you using this ```v-for="item in list"``` instead of this ```v-for="item in list.value"```?

Comment: `v-for` autoescapes the ref's proxy and iterates over an array inside...